# AntDesign tree component – nodes duplicating when moved downstream

Tags: reactjs, tree, antd

I have a Tree component from AntDesign in which the Nodes are draggable.

I have an onDrop function that handles updates the tree state to reflect the new change, anytime the user drags and drops a node.

The types of Nodes are Directory or File. A File or Directory can be dragged into a Directory, but nothing can be dragged into a File.

Problem is that when I drag a File down a Directory and into a File, it correctly moves the File into that Directory but incorrectly duplicates it.

```
const onDrop: TreeProps['onDrop'] = (info) => {
        console.log(info);
        const dropKey = info.node.key;
        const dropKind = info.node.title && nodeKind(info.node.title.toString());
        const dragKind = info.dragNode.title && nodeKind(info.dragNode.title.toString());
        const dragKey = info.dragNode.key;
        const dropPos = info.node.pos.split('-');
        const dropPosition = info.dropPosition - Number(dropPos[dropPos.length - 1]);

        const data = [...treeData];

        // Find dragObject
        let dragObj: DataNode;
        walkGraph(data, dragKey, (item, index, arr) => {
            arr.splice(index, 1);
            dragObj = item;
        });

        if (!info.dropToGap) {
            // TODO: FIX: why does this WalkGraph execute twice?
            walkGraph(data, dropKey, (item, i, _data, parent) => {
                console.log("Executing walkGraph on node: ", item)
                if (item.title && nodeKind(item.title.toString()) === 'file') {
                    // If the node is dragged onto a file, don't insert it as a child.
                    // Insert it as a sibling
                    console.log("Inserting as sibling...")
                    if (!parent) return;
                    parent.children = parent.children || [];
                    parent.children.unshift(dragObj);
                    return;
                }
                item.children = item.children || [];
                item.children.unshift(dragObj);
            });
        } else if (
            ((info.node as any).props.children || []).length > 0 && // Has children
            (info.node as any).props.expanded && // Is expanded
            dropPosition === 1 // On the bottom gap
        ) {
            // Handles user dragging a node to the bottom of a parent node or the list.
            walkGraph(data, dropKey, (item) => {
                item.children = item.children || [];
                item.children.unshift(dragObj);
            });
        } else {
            let ar: DataNode[] = []; // The target array the node will reside in.
            let i: number;
            walkGraph(data, dropKey, (_item, index, arr) => {
                ar = arr;
                i = index;
            });
            if (dropPosition === -1) {
                // Insert at the beginning
                ar.splice(i!, 0, dragObj!);
            } else {
                // Insert at the end
                ar.splice(i! + 1, 0, dragObj!);
            }
        }
        setTreeData(data);
    };
```